# Is there a way to run some logic / function on a route match in react router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Let's say I have a route as follows:

```
const runWhenRouteIs123 = () => {}

<Routes>
  <Route path="123" element={<div>hello</div>} />
  ... // other routes
<Routes>
```

I want the function `runWhenRouteIs123()` to run whenever the route is "whateverIsBefore/123". The function uses React Redux to dispatch some logic.
Previously it was possible as things were rendering using `render()` which allows running logic beforehand. Short circuit evaluation will not work for me as a warning is thrown saying "cannot update component while another component is rendered".

I previously tried this but got the above warning:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="123" element={dispatch(xyz()) && <div>hello</div>} />
  ... // other routes
<Routes>
```

Let me know if more clarification is needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [useMatch](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-match) to compute if there is a/the currently matched route, and run the `runWhenRouteIs123` function as a side-effect. `useMatch` returns a match object if there's a match, otherwise it returns null.

```js
import {
  Routes,
  Route,
  useMatch,
} from 'react-router-dom';

...

const isRoute123 = useMatch("/123");

useEffect(() => {
  const runWhenRouteIs123 = () => {};

  if (isRoute123) {
    runWhenRouteIs123();
  }
}, [isRoute123]);


<Routes>
  <Route path="123" element={<div>hello</div>} />
  ... // other routes
<Routes>
```

Alternatively you could move `runWhenRouteIs123` down to the routed component and call from a `useEffect` hook when it mounts.

Example:

```
const Component123 = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    runWhenRouteIs123();
  }, []);

  return <div>hello</div>;
}
```

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="123" element={<Component123 />} />
  ... // other routes
<Routes>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this is one way to go about this and certainly works and gets the job done. Is there any other production level way to go about this?

With using useEffect, due to the component mounting, the logic inside runs twice which I feel like can be improved. Thoughts? 

Not disregarding anything you've said, your answer is useful, looking to improve on it!

Comment: @NihirSingh If you are specifically referring to components being mounted twice or certain lifecycle methods/functions running twice as a result of the component being rendered within the `React.StrictMode` component, this is a non-production build dev tool. In other words, in production builds they run only once. If there is some asynchronous logic you are running in the effect then you'll want to properly clean up resources/subscriptions/network requests/etc in a cleanup function returned from `useEffect`.